# Normalizar en PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy tratando de mostrar imágenes en un directorio; las carga, pero el problema es que algunas se cargan correctamente y hay muchas que no se cargan bien, es decir, me figura que pesa 0KB (esto me pasa con las imágenes PNG y muchas de las JPG).

Mi pregunta es ¿cómo puedo normalizar para saber qué tipo de imagen se debe mostrar?

Mi código en PHP es el siguiente:

```
<?php
include 'conexion.php';

$consulta = "SELECT p.progenid, ip.ImaAsoId, ip.ImaAsoIma, ip.ImaAsoExt
        FROM productogenerico p 
        LEFT JOIN imagenasociada ip
        ON p.progenid = ip.perid
        WHERE ip.ImaAsoIma IS NOT NULL
        ORDER BY p.progenid";

$resultado = $conexion->query($consulta);

$ruta = 'imagenes3/';
if($resultado = $conexion->query($consulta)){
   while($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
    var_dump($fila);

    $archivo = $fila['progenid'] . '.' . $fila['ImaAsoExt'];
    if($archivo== "image/jpg" || $archivo== "image/jpeg" || $archivo== "image/png" || $archivo== "image/gif"){
        file_put_contents($ruta . $archivo, $fila['ImaAsoIma']);
        #$conexion->query('UPDATE imagenasociada SET ImaAsoIma = NULL WHERE ImaAsoId = ' . $fila['ImaAsoId']);
    }
}
}else{
echo "Error al conectarse: ".$conexion->error;
}

?>
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122765/discussion-on-question-by-stephanierm-normalizar-en-php).

Comment: Te da algún error o solo no muestra las imágenes?

Comment: Por favor, movi todos los comentarios a un chat, pueden seguir la conversacion alli...

Comment: @Davidflogar te respondí en el chat

Answer (score 0):

Si te refieres a "filtrar"(por llamarlo de alguna forma) las imagenes que se suben puedes hacer esto

`if($imagen== "image/jpg" || $imagen== "image/jpeg" || $imagen== "image/png" || $imagen== "image/gif")`

De esa forma todo lo que pongas desde de **/** va a ser el formato que quieres

Comment: lo que quiero es justamente poder mostrar todos los tipos de imagenes que tengo, en este caso: jpg, png, y gif, ya que solo me muestra las jpg

Comment: Probé agregando ese if que tú me dices, pero no me funcionó porque no me cargó las imagenes, en la pregunta de arriba quedó editado mi código